# Image loads only when page reloads (HTML5 Canvas)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When I load the page for the first time, nothing shows up but when I reload the page the image shows up. How to load the image on first page load? I referred to a few answers on SO, and found that I could use `onload` but the thing is that I am calling `head.draw()` from another function at a certain time.

```
let head_ = new Image();
head_.src = "img/head.png";

const head = {
    x : 12,
    y : 12,
    w : 36,
    h : 36,
    draw : function(){
        ctx.drawImage(head_, 0, 0, head_.width, head_.height, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }
}

function draw(){
    // SOME CODE
    head.draw();
    // SOME CODE
}

function loop(){
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

And also all the other images are loading fine even on the first load. This concerns me more!!!

Is there any way to forcefully load the images?

Comment: take a look at this, window.onload seems like something you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload

Comment: @Omiinahellcat I tried this but no luck :(

Comment: Where is `abcd` function called?

Comment: You can try:
if (head_.complete) {
        ctx.drawImage(...);
} else {
img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(...);
}
}

Comment: Well, it's the `draw()` function. I have edited my question.

Comment: @smartilabs Same behavior :(

Comment: @KobayakiTunnel can you create a snippet online where you can duplicate this behaviour? Easier to help...